Properties of the Function f ( x ) = x − { x } : A Mathematical Analysis
Given the definition: If $m-\frac{1}{2}<x≤m+\frac{1}{2}$ (where m is an integer), then m is called the nearest integer to the real number x, denoted as {x}, that is, {x}=m. Among the following four statements about the function f(x)= x-{x}, the correct ones are ( )
A. The domain of the function y=f(x) is R, and the range is
$(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$
B. The function y=f(x) is an even function
C. The function y=f(x) is an odd function
D. The function y=f(x) is monotonically increasing on $(-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}]$
My method is as follows:
f[x_] := x - Round[x];


domain = "R"; 
range = Simplify[Reduce[Element[y, Reals], y]];
Print["Domain: ", domain];
Print["Range: ", range];


oddQ = Simplify[f[-x] == -f[x]]; 
evenQ = Simplify[f[-x] == f[x]]; 
Print["Is the function odd? ", oddQ];
Print["Is the function even? ", evenQ];


monotonicity = Simplify[D[f[x], x] > 0]; 
Print["Is the function monotonically increasing on (-1/2, 1/2]? ", 
  monotonicity];

Plot[f[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotLabel -> "Graph of f(x) = x - {x}", 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "f(x)"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, Thick}]


Is there another way to solve this problem?

All those properties are implemented in Mathematica.
f[x_?NumericQ] := x - Round[x]
ResourceFunction["EvenFunctionQ"][f[x], x]


False

ResourceFunction["OddFunctionQ"][f[x], x]


True

ResourceFunction["FunctionMonotonicity",  ResourceSystemBase -> 
   "https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/resourcesystem/api/1.0"][f[x], x]


<|"Increasing" -> False, "Decreasing" -> False, "Constant" -> False|>

FunctionDomain[f[x], x]


True

FunctionRange[f[x], x, y, Reals]


$Aborted[]

It's strange: the latest command fails for me in 14.1 on Windows.
Addition. In 14.1 on Windows
FunctionMonotonicity[{x - Round[x], -1/2 < x < 1/2}, x]


1


on 12.0.1 , the lastest one returns FunctionRange::nmet: Unable to find the range with the available methods.
